# Passport not destroying auth session for Google

Tags: node.js, session, express

Passport's documentation says [its `req.logout` function will destroy any existing session and other passport/user data](http://passportjs.org/guide/logout/)

I am running into an issue whereby when I do `req.logout()` it does indeed destroy the session, but if I go back to `/auth/google` I am immediately logged in again because it seems that Google itself remembers my credentials.

How do I clear my credentials with Google Passport?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot control the session cookie for Google (or any other auth provider for that matter). You could attempt to redirect the user to Google's logout page.

Think about it this way, when I logout of your site I am not expecting to also be logged out of Google.

Comment: I don't need to log them out of Google but I want the Google authentication with my app to be destroyed. Actually with another app I am using, `req.logout()` seems to do this automatically. I haven on idea why it's not working with my other app since the code seems largely the same, but the redirect to `/auth/google` doesn't automatically log them in again

Comment: Never mind, it's just that you will be taken to the account chooser if there is more than one account to log in with again.  Is there any other way to handle this?

Comment: @ExplosionPills take a look at [Google's Authentication URI parameters](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenIDConnect#authenticationuriparameters), specifically using [`{ prompt : 'consent' }`](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenIDConnect#re-consent).

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a quite old question, but I was in the same situation as yours, and following [@idbehold comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28842241/passport-not-destroying-auth-session-for-google#comment-45955018) I achieved, not to logging the user's Google account out, but forcing the **/google/auth** to pick an account:

```
app.get('/auth/google', passport.authenticate('google', {
    scope: [
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'
    ],
    prompt: 'select_account'
}));
```

With that, I avoid redirecting them to the Google's logout page (and therefore, not logging out from every single Google service), and also letting the user choose between their accounts.

Hope this still helps :)